# Changing the text position based on width of a button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am dealing with some responsive design and would like to move the text in a button if certain string is above 37 characters AND if the width of a button is above a certain width.

So far I managed to move the text based on the string.length however when I introduce the second condition I am having issues.

```
<div class="button">
  <p>I am a button<p>
</div>
```

I also have a list of variables that change the text in the button based on some previous result. Here is what I have tried:

```
//searches my list for what text to put
var textLength = list[country].text.length

//trying to find the width of the button 
var buttonLength = $('.button').width();

//display the width, do not see it in dev tools, having issue here
console.log(buttonLength);

          if(textLength > 37 && buttonLength > 309 ){
           $('.button p').css('bottom', '0.9em'); 
          };
```

I believe that the problem may lay with my syntax. Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: if you want to change the position of the element. then add $('.button p').css('position', 'relative');

Comment: @techLove, thanks for the reply, I probably should have added some css also. The text is already relative, I am having issues with the second condition of the if statement

Comment: try to use offsetWidth instead of width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...Would like to move the text in a button if certain string is above
>   37 characters AND if the width of a button is less than a certain
>   width.

Thus, your if statement is :

```
if(textLength > 37 && buttonLength > 309 )
```

You should try this :

```
if(textLength > 37 && buttonLength < 309 )
```

### EDIT :

As the if statement is not the issue, I assume your div has a padding css property which is not computed with `.width()` method.
Instead use `.outerWidth()` as mentionned in jQuery's doc:

> Get the current computed outer width (including padding, border, and
>   optionally margin) for the first element in the set of matched
>   elements or set the outer width of every matched element.

Here's a working fiddle :

```js
var textLength = $('#text').html().length,
  divWidth = $('#test').outerWidth();

if (textLength > 14 && divWidth > 300) {
 alert("Text is "+ textLength + " characters, div is " + divWidth+ "px wide");
  $('#text').css('transform', 'translateY(0.9em)');
}
else {
 alert("Not in condition");
}
```

```css
#test {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 100px;
  background: springgreen;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}
#text {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
<p id="text">fsqdfdgfdgfdfgdf</p>
</div>
```

Also, instead of `bottom: 0.9em`, use `transform` property.

Comment: I apologise, I typed this in a hurry. I meant above not less, I have fixed it in the OP. Good catch!